# Switch learning MAC addresses

Tags: switch

I know how switch learns MAC addresses after startup, but what I'm not sure about is, when the switch floods a frame (when it doesn't know the destination) does the source port (that sent the frame) also receive the frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No. Broadcasts are flooded out all interfaces except the one which they were received on. If they were sent on that interface too then you'd have a never ending flow of broadcast traffic.

Answer (score 5):

@OzNetNerd answer is correct however the term you choose could cause some confusion.

- When a host attached to a switch send a *broadcast* frame, the switch replicate it to all ports, except the port on which the frame was received.
- When the switch receive an *unicast* frame destined to an unknown mac address, the switch will *flood* it to all ports, except the port on which the frame was received. The frame is still a unicast tough, and not a broadcast.

Comment: Ah, I suggested an edit to change *broadcast* to *flood* in the question before I read this answer. Sorry if that results in this answer making less sense if the edit is approved.

Comment: Great answer @JFL. Hopefully the OP will see it too.